# Working with subdomains in Yii2

Tags: url, subdomain, yii2

What is the best way to get subdomain info (*http://**s1**.**s2**.site.com*)?

And is there a quick way of creating an url with another subdomain
*http://**s1**.**s2**.site.com* => *http://**s3**.**s4**.site.com* ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with PHP parse url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
 <?php
  $url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';
  from php manual  
  var_dump(parse_url($url));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
  var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

and much other

eventually   `explode`  (php function) the part you need to decompose

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if it is the best way but I use the following code:

```
$domain= strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);    // "s1.s2.domain.com"
$position= strrpos($domain, '.domain.com');
$subdomain= substr($domain, 0, $position);
```